# Ion-Thumbnail clickable with value

Tags: ionic2

I have a col with image as follows:

```
<ion-col *ngIf="i < items?.length">
            <ion-thumbnail  item-left (click)="clicked()">
              <img width="100px" height="150px" src="somevalue" />
            </ion-thumbnail>
            
            <h6>{{ items[i].dealTitle }}</h6>
            <p><ion-badge color="danger">{{ items[i].somevalue }}  days left</ion-badge></p>
            <p>Like this deal</p>
  </ion-col>
```

I have ion-thumbnail clickable as I have a function in my component as follows:

```
clicked(){
}
```

I want to pass some id to clicked function. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake. I removed `{{}}` in `(click)="clicked({{id}})"`.